# How to upload scores on facebook after win a game in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c

I just completed my game. ( well not 100%). I am at the upload on facebook part. Could you guys share any resource or knowledge how to implement it please? after finish the game, i will have a button called: upload on facebook. click that and it will straightaway show the log in page for me to enter the username and password. Then I will be able to upload my scores for that game. Hmm yes this is a question of mine too, how to upload the scores?

I really appreciate for any helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Facebook Connect for iPhone](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone)